# OpenCV: Projection matrices from Fundamental matrix and SolvePnPRansac are totally different

Tags: c#, opencv, matrix, 3d

As part of my master thesis I am exploring Structure From Motion. After reading parts of the [H&Z book](http://www.robots.ox.ac.uk/~vgg/hzbook/index.html), following online tutorials and reading through many SO posts I have some useful results, but I have also some problems. I'm using OpenCVSharp wrapper. All images are taken with the same camera.

What I have now:

---

First I calculate initial 3d points coordinates. I do this with these steps:

1. Calculate Farneback's dense optical flow.
2. Find the Fundamental matrix using Cv2.FindFundamentalMat with RANSAC
3. Get Essential matrix using camera intrinsics (at this point I use pre-determined intrinsics) and decompose it:

   ```
   Mat essential = camera_matrix.T() * fundamentalMatrix * camera_matrix;

   SVD decomp = new SVD(essential, OpenCvSharp.SVDFlag.ModifyA);

   Mat diag = new Mat(3, 3, MatType.CV_64FC1, new double[] {
       1.0D, 0.0D, 0.0D,
       0.0D, 1.0D, 0.0D,
       0.0D, 0.0D, 0.0D
   });

   Mat Er = decomp.U * diag * decomp.Vt;

   SVD svd = new SVD(Er, OpenCvSharp.SVDFlag.ModifyA);

   Mat W = new Mat(3, 3, MatType.CV_64FC1, new double[] {
       0.0D, -1.0D, 0.0D,
       1.0D, 0.0D, 0.0D,
       0.0D, 0.0D, 1.0D
   });

   Mat Winv = new Mat(3, 3, MatType.CV_64FC1, new double[] {
       0.0D, 1.0D, 0.0D,
       -1.0D, 0.0D, 0.0D,
       0.0D, 0.0D, 1.0D
   });

   Mat R1 = svd.U * W * svd.Vt;
   Mat T1 = svd.U.Col[2];
   Mat R2 = svd.U * Winv * svd.Vt;
   Mat T2 = -svd.U.Col[2];

   Mat[] Ps = new Mat[4];

   for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
       Ps[i] = new Mat(3, 4, MatType.CV_64FC1);

   Cv2.HConcat(R1, T1, Ps[0]);
   Cv2.HConcat(R1, T2, Ps[1]);
   Cv2.HConcat(R2, T1, Ps[2]);
   Cv2.HConcat(R2, T2, Ps[3]);
   ```
4. Then I check which projection matrix has the most points in front of both cameras by triangulating the points and then multiplying them by projection matrices (I tried both Cv2.TriangulatePoints and H&Z version with similar results) and checking for positive Z values (after converting from homogenous values):

   ```
   P * point3D
   ```
5. At this point I should have more or less correct 3D points. The 3D visualization looks quite correct.

---

Then I calculate SolvePNP for every new frame by using again the dense optical flow and with the previous projection matrix known I calculate next 3D points and add them to the model. Again 3D visualization looks more or less correct (no bundle adjustment at this point).

Since I need to use SolvePNP for every new frame I started by checking it with the one calculated for the first 2 images with the fundamental matrix. Theoretically the projection matrix should be the same or almost the same as the one calculated with the initial algorithm - I use the initial 3D points and the corresponding 2D points in the second image. But it's not the same.

Here is the one calculated by decomposing the fundamental matrix:

```
0,955678480016302 -0,0278536127242155 0,293091827064387 -0,148461857222772 
-0,0710609269521247 0,944258717203142 0,321443338158658 -0,166586733489084 
0,285707870900394 0,328023857736121 -0,900428432059693 0,974786098164824
```

And here is the one I got from the SolvePnPRansac:

```
0,998124823499476 -0,0269266503551759 -0,0549708305812315 -0,0483615883381834 
0,0522887223187244 0,8419572918112 0,537004476968512 -2,0699592377647 
0,0318233598542908 -0,538871853288516 0,841786433426546 28,7686946357429
```

Both of them look like correct projection matrices, but they are different.

For those patient people who read the whole post I have 3 questions:

```
1. Why are these matrices different? I know the reconstruction is up to scale, but since I have an arbitrary scale assigned in the first place the SolvePNP should keep that scale.
2. I noticed one strange thing - the translation in the first matrix seems to be exactly the same no matter what images I use.
3. Is the overal algorithm correct, or am I doing something wrong? Do I miss some important step?
```

If more code is required let me know and I will edit the question.

Thank You!

Comment: On line 1 of your post I was lost because I had no idea what "the H&Z book" is even though, as it turns out, there is a well worn copy on my bookshelf. YOu could easily have provided a link to Hartley and Zisserman's "Multiple View Geometry in Computer Vision" http://www.robots.ox.ac.uk/~vgg/hzbook/index.html

Comment: Thank You for Your comment, I edited the question with Your link. Before, I thought everybody with some knowledge on the subject would know what book I'm talking about.

Answer (score 7):

**To begin with**, there is one obvious reason why the two approaches you described are unlikely to provide the exact same projection matrices : they both estimate their results using RANSAC, which is an algorithm based on randomness. As both approaches randomly select some of the correspondences in order to estimate a model fitting a majority of them, the result depend on the chosen correspondences.

Hence, you cannot expect to obtain *exactly* the same projection matrices with both approaches. However, if everything were OK, they should be quite close, which does not seem to be the case. The two matrices that you showed have very different translation, **indicating that there probably is a more serious problem**.

**First**, the fact that "the translation in the first matrix seems to be exactly the same no matter what images I use" seems to me a strong clue that there might be a bug in your implementation. I would suggest to first investigate this in detail.

**Second**, I do not think that using Optical Flow in a Structure From Motion workflow is appropriate. Indeed, Optical Flow requires the two considered images to be very close (e.g. two successive frames of a video), whereas 3D triangulation of corresponding points in two images requires a large baseline in order to be accurate. These two requirements are contradictory, which might lead to problems and inaccuracies in the results, hence explaining the different results of the two approaches.

For instance, if the two images you consider are two successive video frames, you will not be able to triangulate points accurately, which might lead to the selection of the wrong projection matrix in step 4 and might also cause `SolvePnP` to estimate a wrong projection matrix. On the other hand, if the two images you consider have a large baseline, triangulation will be accurate but Optical Flow will probably have a lot of mismatches, which will introduce errors in the whole workflow.

**One thing you could do**, in order to understand where your problems are coming from, would be to use synthetical data with known projection matrices and 3D points. Then, you could analyze the accuracy of each step and check if they generate the expected results.

Comment: Thank You very much for Your answer! As You wrote - I don't expect the matrices to be a 100% match, and the rotations seem similar. But the translations are way off even when scaled - although I believe SolvePnP should handle the scale correctly when points are normalized. I use a high framerate video and calculate optical flow every frame, but do the triangulation only when the differences have reached a reasonable threshold, so I don't think that is a problem.

Comment: I tested synthetic data - the SolvePnP function gives the correct results, but still, the triangulation result seems ok when visualized, and I can't find any incorrect part of it. So the question is still open.

Comment: @PrzemysławWrzesiński In your post you said "since I have an arbitrary scale assigned in the first place the SolvePNP should keep that scale", how exactly do you assign an arbitrary scale? Because from what I understand, the norm of the translation of the estimated projection matrix should be one, since it is a column vector of matrix `svd.U` which is orthogonal. Hence, there is something definitely odd with the scale of the translation vector returned by `solvePnP`.

Comment: That and the fact that "the translation in the first matrix seems to be exactly the same no matter what images I use" are two things that should be investigated in details, which will be hard to do without the complete source code ...

Comment: Sorry for long time no response, I'm testing the initial triangulation - no results yet. I don't believe though that the norm of the translation should be one - the movement is not constrained to be exactly the distance of one. I gave You +1 to the answer because You clearly put some effort into it, but it's not accepted answer because it does not solve my problem. Will write here if I have a solution.

Comment: @Przemyslaw unless you explicitly multiply T1 and T2 by a scaling factor, the norm of the translation _will_ be 1. Just see how T1 and T2 are defined as + or - the second column of the orthogonal matrix `svd.U`...

Comment: Thanks, just checked that - You are right. So the translation for the first triangulation should be multiplied by scale. It's a step forward, though it still doesn't explain the differences between matrices. Will do further research. Thanks again!

Answer (score 1):

I'm writing to let everyone know that I did not succed in solving this problem - I used the fundamental matrix initial triangulation and than SolvePnP despite knowing that the results are incorrect. It is not a perfect solution, but sometimes it works. It was enough for my whole project to be accepted and for me to graduate :)

Answer (score 1):

I know I am a bit late to this party, but I would like to point out a fundamental difference between your two approaches. The camera pose you get from the essential matrix is up to scale, while the camera pose you get from solvePnP should be in world units. In other words, the translation vector you get from the essential matrix is a unit vector, while the magnitude of the translation vector you get from solvePnP should be close to the actual distance between the camera and the origin of the coordinate system.